# Merge and Rebase options using eclipse push to branch in Remote

Tags: eclipse, git

I have my own Git branch (branch-A) and branch-A having remote reference also origin/branch-A.
I did one modification and saved the changes into my local repository. Next when I am tying to publish my commits into others via ECLIPSE push commit - I get a new pop up window like below [image]

Here I can see some extra merge and rebase options from the upstream remote.
By default it is auto selecting 'Merge upstream commits into local branch' and on more options is 'Rebase commits of local branch onto upstream'.

Can you please give some explanation on these two options while pushing the changes to remote.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 2):

When doing a pull

- Merge upstream commits into local branch

  Will apply modifications from your upstream on top of your commits and finally will add a new commit, inform you of merging, normally by a message which starts with: **Merge** ...
- Rebase commits of local branch onto upstream

  Will apply modifications from your upstream first, then apply your's on top of them and does not create any additional commits about merging.

So the first option will pollute your **History** with a lot of commits include **Merge ...** , **Merge ...**, **Merge ...** because we are doing so mush pull to sync with upstream. but the second option will create a *clear* history that narrates our versioning without **Merge ...** parasites !!!

Comment: ok i understand rebase and merge.

Few mints back i try to push my changes with options (when doing a pull) i selected option Merge upstream commits into local branch.
then i used Next options i got Error : non-Fast_forward which means my local and remote not update right OK .

so here i used both options while pushing , but i got above error i used options Merge upstream commits into local branch/Rebase commits of local branch onto upstream.

why my remote changes will be not merging with my local ?

Comment: These options are **pull options** and does not have anything to do with **push**. Everytime you decide to *push* first do a *pull* with second option and then do *push*.

Comment: Good answer, but it seems you are really upselling the rebase option without consideration of the trade-off - rewriting history will require forced pushes and forced/rebase pulls on behalf of others working on that branch. This is usually just fine/normal for topical feature branches, but generally undesirable for master and release branches.

Comment: Just to clarify my previous comment, this should only be an issue when using multiple remotes.

Comment: Thanks lot Nitro,
I agree with your point. 
Let say i have single local commit at the same time my co-workers already pushed his changes in to branch ok .
Now i am trying to push my commit with option (Rebase commits of local branch onto upstream) here why remote changes will be not updating with my local working copy ?

Comment: Because you just did a push. push and pull are two distinct operation and does not have any hooks on each other. you should do them manually.

Comment: Ok fine. So these two options are (Merge upstream commits into local branch/Rebase commits of local branch onto upstream) is not work without pull , when i am doing push right ?

Comment: Yes, It configures upstream for push and pull, and then sets up selected option for subsequent pulls on this branch.